# Express.js doesn't redirect to custom URL scheme

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently trying to redirect the user to a custom URL scheme with Express.js to open an app installed on my iPad (using "example://").

Here's my code that should redirect to the URL when a button gets pressed on a page running on a different server:

```
const { response } = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');
const smartMirror = express();


router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/test.html'));
});

smartMirror.use('/', router);
smartMirror.listen(process.env.port || 8000);

console.log('Running on Port 8000');

smartMirror.get("/launch", (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(302, "touchpoint://");
    res.status(200);
})
```

In the console the error says "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: node-fetch cannot load [object Request]. URL scheme "touchpoint" is not supported."

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You've misidentified the problem. It hasn't go anything to do with Express telling the client it has been redirected, it is because you are trying to access the URL with `fetch`.

Whatever application `touchpoint://` has been registered to be handled with, you need to *navigate* to the URL.

`fetch("touchpoint://")` won't work (and this is what you are doing, just via a redirect).

This is for much the same reason that `<img src="touchpoint://">` wouldn't work if you tried that.

You need to actually navigate to it. e.g.

`<a href="touchpoint://">` or `location = "touchpoint://"`.

Comment: Oh I understand! But how do I actually do it? Let's say I have a bool that gets set to true as soon as the "signal" arrives at Port 8000. if(something == true){ window.location = "touchpoint://"; } doesn't do anything. Sorry if this is stupid, I don't code as much

Comment: Oh and just to clarify I'm using NodeJS to start the servers